# Selenium: scraping and print classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my first time using Selenium. I've looked at other questions in StackOverflow before, but they haven't been very helpful to me. I would like to print "only" the text Giornata 38 and Giornata 37 from the website https://link. No the content, but only these two texts for illustrative purposes. I specify that everything is for educational, study and formative purposes only for myself that I am learning Python.

What am I doing wrong? Python code or html inspection on the site? IMPORTANT: If I have written the code wrong and you modify / improve it, remember to stay Firefox, do not replace it with Chrome. Thank you

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('link')

giornata = browser.find_element_by_class_name("event__round event__round--static")
print(giornata)

browser.quit()
display.stop()
```

Error: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .event__round event__round--static

Comment: Please add the result of `print(giornata)` or an error you've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `event__round event__round--static` contains a space `" "`, you have to remove this space and connect the class with a dot `.`.

Instead of:

```
giornata = browser.find_element_by_class_name("event__round event__round--static")
```

Try:

```
giornata = browser.find_element_by_class_name("event__round.event__round--static")
print(giornata.text)
```

---

Based on your comment, if you want to access specific elements, such as "Giornata 37" and "Giornata 38", you can use the [`:nth-of-type(n)`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) CSS selector, `div.event__round:nth-of-type(2)` will select a `div` and then the second class `event__round`.

In your example:

```
print(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.event__round:nth-of-type(15)").text)
print(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.event__round:nth-of-type(2)").text)
```

Output:

```
Giornata 37
Giornata 38
```

Comment: Thanks so much. But I wanted to write both Day 38 and Day 37 (as written in the question), like this: Giornata 37, Giornata 38. Not only Giornata 38. P.S: Have you controlled if my written Python code is good? Specifically did you control the inspected html code of the link? I don't know if it's enough to just write "event__round.event__round - static". Shouldn't I also specify divs or classes within classes? Can you edit your answer please?  Thank you :)

Comment: @FrederickMan So you want `Giornata 37` and `Giornata 38` in the output?  also, note, here on SO, we don't write code for you, if you have a specific question we can help you.

Comment: In the question I had explicitly asked that I needed Day 38 and Day 37. I don't add it in the comment. Perhaps you have read my question absently. Anyway thank you for the answer. Very kind